# How can I display ShowCaseView when my listview is empty

Tags: android, listview, showcaseview

I created CustomListView. now I want to Show, 'ShowCaseView' when I get my listview is empty. Will It possible or not.

Comment: It is possible, check if list size is 0 and proceed to show the showcaseview

Comment: check if `array==null || array.isEmpty()` then show ShowCaseView else show listview.

Comment: How can I handle notifyDataSetChanged() method. because in my case it will automatically refresh listview?

Comment: Is there any way, so that i display ShowcaseView while  listview.setEmptyView ()  method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps before initialization run or check size != 0

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a ShowCaseView with no target since your list view is empty you can use;

```
 ShowcaseView.Builder showCaseViewBuild = new ShowcaseView.Builder(mActivity)
.setTarget(Target.NONE)
.[your_other_configuration_stuff_here];
```

And then if you are trying to trigger this when the list view is empty, you can set a listener for changes to the ListView hierarchy like;

```
ListView lv = new ListView(mActivity);
//[your ListView setup code here... then the listener below]

lv.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
        // trigger your ShowCaseView here when no children are left
        // TODO
    }
});
```